# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in laravel apiResource

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm creating a CRUD API in Laravel 7 using resource collection but when i try to send data using post request it gives

**Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. in file D:\xampp\htdocs\safaripet\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117**

**my route**

```
Route::apiResource('locations','Api\LocationsController');
```

**my controller code**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\Locations as LocationsResource;
use App\Locations;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Validator;

 class LocationsController extends Controller
 {
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function index()
 {
    return new LocationsResource(Locations::paginate(3));
 }

 /**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $request->validate([
        'location_name' => 'required|unique:locations',
    ], 
    [
        'location_name.required' => 'Enter name',
        'location_name.unique' => 'location name already exist',
    ]);
    
    $locations = new Locations();
    $locations->location_name = $request->location_name;
    $locations->slug = Str::slug($request->location_name);
    $locations->save();
    
    return new LocationsResource($locations);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

[image]

please help me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are posting to `http://localhost:8000/locations`, while your routes list clearly defines the URI `http://localhost:8000/api/locations`

Comment: sir thanks for your response now it just return my blade file

Comment: What blade file? Please verify your `store` function gets triggered, for example by adding a `dump` at the start of the function. Are you sending the correct authentication headers with your post request? Maybe you are redirected to login page?

Comment: In header in send Content-Type application/json

Comment: it gives Unexpected '<'

Comment: Isn't your API route behind an auth middleware? And where does it say `Unexpected <`?

Comment: i passed in header Accept: application/json and Content-type: application/json it gives a response but "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'location_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `locations` (`location_name`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, , 2020-10-06 18:46:43, 2020-10-06 18:46:43))",

Comment: it's work now but, I passed the data through raw not formdata...thanks for your response sir